# Relationships manytomany laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am trying to get relations between three tables. The following tables:

```
table: documentsets
docflow_documentset_id
..
..

table: subsets
docflow_subset_id
docflow_documentset_id
..
..

table: subdocuments
docflow_subdocument_id
docflow_subset_id
..
..
```

I am trying to get all the subdocuments belonging to an documentset with an intermediate table subsets.

Primary keys of the tables are:

docflow_documentset_id, docflow_subset_id, docflow_subdocument_id

in my docflow_documentsets model I have the following function:

```php
    public function subdocuments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(docflow_subdocuments::class, 'bvd_pp_prod_docflow_subsets', 'docflow_subset_id', 'docflow_subset_id');
    }
```

and in my docflow_subdocuments the following:

```php
public function documentsets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(docflow_documentsets::class, 'bvd_pp_prod_docflow_subsets', 'docflow_subset_id', 'docflow_subset_id');
    }
```

somehow the documentsets function in de docflow_subdocuments is not called at all, its driving me nuts why this is happening :(

Can anybody help out here?

EDIT:

migrations:

```php
Schema::create('bvd_pp_prod_docflow_documentsets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('docflow_documentset_id');
        $table->integer('docflow_id');
        $table->string('docflow_documentset_name', 50)->nullable();
        $table->string('docflow_documentset_type', 50)->nullable();
    });

Schema::create('bvd_pp_prod_docflow_subsets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('docflow_subset_id');
        $table->integer('docflow_documentset_id');
        $table->boolean('docflow_subset_staple');
    });

Schema::create('bvd_pp_prod_docflow_subdocuments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('docflow_subdocument_id');
        $table->integer('docflow_subset_id');
        $table->string('docflow_subdocument_document', 50);
        $table->string('docflow_subdocument_stamp', 50);
        $table->string('docflow_subdocument_mediatype', 50);
        $table->boolean('docflow_subdocument_duplex');
    });
```

Comment: do you have set `foreign key` constraint in your tables `subsets` and `subdocuments` for `docflow_subset_id`?

Comment: show your migration files for tables

Comment: @LeenaPatel added the migration files :)

Comment: Try checking the official documentation [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships). I guess you defined the belongs to many relation is not accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution:

```
/**
 * Get subdocuments belonging to this documentset with intermediate model
 */
public function subdocuments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
            docflow_subdocuments::class, 
            docflow_subsets::class,
            'docflow_documentset_id',
            'docflow_subset_id'
        );
}
```

gives me te result I want,
Is this because I created foreign keys on the tables?

Answer (score 0):

You should create models with belongsTo and hasMany

In docflow_documentset:

```
public function subsets(){
    return $this->hasMany(docflow_subset::class);
}
```

In docflow_subset:

```
public function subdocuments(){
    return $this->hasMany(docflow_subdocument::class);
}

public function documentsets(){
    return $this->belongsTo(docflow_documentset::class, 'docflow_documentset_id');
}
```

In docflow_subdocument:

```
public function subsets(){
    return $this->belongsTo(docflow_subset::class, 'docflow_subset_id');
}
```

Comment: ``$subdocuments = docflow_documentsets::find([id])->subdocuments;`` still gives me nothing :(

Comment: You can not access to sub document from document directly. because there isn't any relation between document and sub document without subset table. 
@PatrickRennings